# constructing an expertise based bayesian network in causalnex

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, causality

Up to now, in causalnex package, I only encountered Bayesian networks that were constucted from
data. I want to know how to create my own network with my node parameters and CPDs from expertise. Anybody has some reference to it or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like **causalnex** doesn't directly support setting the CPD's manually, but you can look at the underlying code and see that it's using the **pgmpy** BayesianModel to simultaneously represent the structure and CPD's within a **causalnex** BayesianNetwork.

With that, you could add the CPD's you know via [add_cpds](https://pgmpy.org/models.html#pgmpy.models.BayesianModel.BayesianModel.add_cpds) instead of fitting them.  To get at the `BayesianModel` object it would be: `bn._model`, where `bn` is your `causalnex.BayesianNetwork` object.

I'm not sure if this would make you just want to use **pgmpy** instead of **causalnex** or not!!  It seems like the big benefit from **causalnex** is its use of the [NOTEARS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01422) algorithm, which helps you build the Weighted Adjacency Matrix for your Directed Graph.  Then again, it also coordinates some plotting for you.

Also, an important note from the [docs](https://causalnex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_tutorial/03_tutorial.html#Fitting-the-Conditional-Distribution-of-the-Bayesian-Network) to remind you that it's not *really* continuous, but discretised/binned:

> Bayesian Networks in CausalNex support only discrete distributions.
> Any continuous features, or features with a large number of
> categories, should be discretised prior to fitting the Bayesian
> Network. Models containing variables with many possible values will
> typically be badly fit, and exhibit poor performance.

Comment: Thanks alot. Just one question, how do you know it uses pgmpy? I only notices it uses networkx classes

Comment: You can see it in in the code here:  https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/causalnex/blob/3897852194d11407ee86810813914a7bec660239/causalnex/network/network.py#L42